# Why is this type annotation in Haskell necessary?

Tags: haskell, overloading, ghc, typeclass

I'm researching how powerful function overloading in GHC is. I've written the following code:

```
class F_third_arg a where
  run_f :: (Integer, a) -> Integer

instance F_third_arg Integer where
  run_f (_, x) = x

instance F_third_arg String where
  run_f (x, _) = x

my_fun :: (F_third_arg a) => Integer -> (a -> Integer)
my_fun x = \a -> run_f(x, a)

main :: IO ()
main = putStrLn $ show( ((my_fun::Integer->(Integer->Integer)) 5) $ 6)
```

(yes, I need -XTypeSynonymInstances -XFlexibleInstances) and I was surprised that the compiler needs the type annotation near the call to `my_fun`. It is applied to two numbers -- what's the problem with infering this annotation? What are the rules of overloading with these two extensions turned on?

Comment: `FlexibleInstances` already implies `TypeSynonymInstances`. `putStrLn . show` is equivalent to `print`. And you can omit quite a lot of parens...

Comment: As for the type **defaulting** (of course the compiler can't _infer_ the type: numerical literals are polymorphic!), I'm not an expert on that, but GHC extended defaulting rules do the job (`{-# LANGUAGE ExtendedDefaultRules #-}` or GHCi). A better way would be `print $ my_fun 5 (6::Integer)`.

Comment: As @leftaroundabout said, it's the defaulting.  Once you have a nonstandard class involved, Haskell defaulting stops.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem with your code is that number literals themselves are already overloaded. So the literal `6` has type `Num a => a`, while `my_fun 5` has type `F_third_arg b => b -> Integer`. So during type inference, it unifies these two type variables. But as there are no other requirements about them, GHC cannot find a concrete type to use here, and gives an appropriate error message:

```
test.hs:16:26:
    No instance for (F_third_arg a0) arising from a use of `my_fun'
    The type variable `a0' is ambiguous
    Possible fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
    Note: there are several potential instances:
      instance F_third_arg String -- Defined at test.hs:9:10
      instance F_third_arg Integer -- Defined at test.hs:6:10
    In the expression: (my_fun 5)
    In the first argument of `show', namely `((my_fun 5) $ 6)'
    In the second argument of `($)', namely `show ((my_fun 5) $ 6)'

test.hs:16:38:
    No instance for (Num a0) arising from the literal `6'
    The type variable `a0' is ambiguous
    Possible fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
    Note: there are several potential instances:
      instance Num Double -- Defined in `GHC.Float'
      instance Num Float -- Defined in `GHC.Float'
      instance Integral a => Num (GHC.Real.Ratio a)
        -- Defined in `GHC.Real'
      ...plus three others
    In the second argument of `($)', namely `6'
    In the first argument of `show', namely `((my_fun 5) $ 6)'
    In the second argument of `($)', namely `show ((my_fun 5) $ 6)'
```

One might expect that the compiler notices that `Integer` is the only type that fulfils both requirements, but such heuristics would make your code relatively fragile, i.e. it would break just because you add a new instance (e.g. `F_third_arg Double`). Therefore the compiler rejects the code and asks you to be explicit about the type in question.

You found one way to fix it, but @leftroundabouts’s suggestion of using `6::Integer` is a bit nicer.